# Writing to a test results log for the Nunit plugin for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, nunit

I was wondering if anyone knew if it's possible to write to a log so Jenkins will display it when you are viewing nunit test results.

[image: Jenkins Test Results]
The idea is to have steps of test printed in the white space, the reason for this is so when a test fails its obvious to where it failed due to the console messages. When the a test currently fails on a assert we get an obvious message but we cant always guarantee the test will fail on an assert it may fail to find an object.

I have tried using the following

```
Console.writeline("About to click button x")
```

and

```
TestContext.Out.WriteLine("Message to write to log");
```

but nothing is showing up, is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

When you publish the NUnit Test results with the NUnit Plugin it is converting NUnit XML to JUnit XML.

Publishing it as JUnit XML because when it comes to test result XML in Jenkins all roads lead back to JUnit.

Console.WriteLine will at best emit content to the job console log.  Not the Test Result XML file.